# testing set operation through text file

Tags: java, io

I have implemented some set operations. I have to test the program through text files, but was having some issues. Weird thing is that when I test it with just arrays it works fine, but when i try to achieve the same result with reading through file and putting the same values into arrays I get a different result. The text file has ( same content as arrays c and d):

```
acdec bc
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("tester.txt"));
        String one = sc.next();
        String two = sc.next();

        String a[] = one.split("");
        String b[] = two.split("");


        String[] c = { "a", "c", "d", "e", "c" };
        String[] d = { "b", "c"};

        Set set1 = new Set(a);
        Set set2  = new Set (b);

        //When I run these it works fine
        Set set3 = new Set(c);
        Set set4  = new Set (d);

        System.out.println(set1.union(set2));
        System.out.println(set3.union(set4));

        sc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The output is :

```
{a,b,c,c,c,d,e}
{a,b,c,d,e}
```

Comment: Is `Set` your own implementation? If yes, do you check if an element is in the set by using `==` (identity) or `equals`? If you're using the first, than the Strings are created on runtime and are not identical (but equal). The string literals for `Set set3` and `Set set4` are identical (and equal) because they are in the constant pool and the compiler uses the same instance for the equal string literals.

Comment: Yes it is my own implementation, and yes that was my problem, spent too much time on that, appreciate it!